# Access user information from active directory using C

Tags: c++, c, gcc, active-directory, adsi

I saw about ADSI and found that it works with C/C++. I also found code in Visual C++ to create  a new user. I would like to know how to access a user's information (say his telephone number) from active directory using a C or standard C++ program. I dont have a Visual C++ software.I would also want to know what API/libraries I should use to make this happen. I want to run this program using a standard gcc/g++ compiler that I hav already installed in my system with Windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the right headers, you can use [Active Directory's COM interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in C and C++ alike.

Comment: I got what u said. So where do I get the appropriate headers and library files ? I found no download links or sites to it :(

Comment: I know some interfaces are missing from MinGW's SDK. Maybe you should download the "Microsoft Windows SDK" or "Platform SDK" and then copy the headers with the interfaces and CLSIDs, and translate what doesn't compile on GCC...

Comment: I have found a Microsoft SDK folder in my computer. I tried to link them in execution of the program and found there are more dependencies to solve. Wre can I get a complete package of libraries and headers ?

Comment: I don't see what you could possibly be trying to link, apart from GUIDs. Use `#include <initguid.h>` before the GUID definitions, that way they'll be defined locally.